# Custom chainable decorator for NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, nestjs, decorator

I'm playing around with NestJS and encountered something weird - there is no separation between `null` and `undefined` in the default `IsOptional` decorator. I found this workaround:

```ts
export function IsOptionalNonNullable(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return ValidateIf((_obj: unknown, value: unknown) => {
    if (value === undefined) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }, validationOptions);
}

export function IsNullable(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return ValidateIf((_obj: unknown, value: unknown) => {
    if (value === null) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }, validationOptions);
}
```

.. which does the trick, however, the error message is confusing, as it just uses the next constraint that fails.

I tried doing my own custom validator implementing the `ValidatorConstraintInterface`, but the `validate` function should return a boolean, which in my case is not enough.

Ideally, I would have a `Nullable` decorator, in case it fails I would like to receive a message indicating that `null` is the allowed value.

Comment: You can add default message to a custom decorator validator, in the same way as you would with a class validator. https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-classes

Comment: This doesnt help with the case when I want to modify the message of the main validator indicating that null is a valid value.